How to calculate and compare the apparent likelihood of an interaction between groups of different sizes
I need to compare variation in virus transmission within and between three differnt sized age groups: children (N= 20,000), adults (N= 60,000) and older people (N=20,000). So, within the population, there are 9 possible interactions: child-child, child-adult, child-old, adult-child, adult-adult, adult-old, old-child, old-adult, old-old. Each of these possible interactions can be either x-to-x (an infection from x to x) or x-by-x (an infection of x by x).
From the perspective child-to-x, for example, say there were 2000 child-to-child infections, 4000 child-to-adult and 2000 child-to-older. Can I say, the risks of child to child infection was 10%; child to adults was 20%; and child to elderly people was 10%.
The problem I see is that I can't compare these risks relatively. I can't really say that relative to the child-to-child risk, the child-to-adult risk is 2 times higher - because the adult population is 3x as large, but this is not factored into the calculation. It would be factored into the other perspective, where 4000 adult-by-child infections have a risk of 6.67%.
Is there some way to factor in the size of the to-population in a risk calculation or to combine the two perspectives? Can this actually be calculated as the risk of infection-to and/or -by a specific group? Is this similar to this question/answer, which seems to ignore the possibility of interactions between the same group?

Infection does not happen on a per child basis, but on the interaction child to (infectable) x. Your numbers are only correct if each child interacted with exactly one child, adult and elderly. Also the child to child interaction is difficult, because where do the other kids in the interaction come from.

@LukasLohse - this is exactly what I want to measure: the likelihood of an interaction. While it is not in the question, there is data on the number of contacts AND the number of resulting infections. I want to know who is more likely to have had contact with whom AND who is more likely to have caused an infection - eg, if children were more or less likely to have had contact with other children, adults or old people; and if children were more or less likely to have caused an infection of another child, adult or old person.

@LukasLohse - I'm not sure what you mean by 'where do the other kids in the interaction come from?' If there are 20K kids, 1 is infected, then the infected kid can potentially interact with exactly 20K-1 kids.

A simple binary logit regression can answer your research question. Note that likelihood refers to a specific term in statistics (derivative of probability) and is often misunderstood by the public, so researchers should avoid using it in public communication. In medical research, risk refers to the probability of contracting a disease, which is clearer to understand and communicate.
What you have seems to be a crosstabulation of the count of infection, but there is confusion between who are the infectors and who are the infected, as both have different totals. The model, instead, should use the following variables:

Response: the number of people getting infected at a specific infector-infectee combination, out of the total number of people exposed to the risk at the same infector-infectee combination. Note that this response variable is represented by both a numerator and denominator to give a probability.
Infector: a three-category factor infector representing whether the infector is children, adults, or elder (Coded C, A, E, respectively).
Infectee: a three-category factor infectee representing whether the infector is children, adults, or elder (Coded c, a, e, respectively).

Overall, infector introduces two coefficients (e.g., of A and E, respectively, using C as the reference group), infectee introduces another two coefficients (e.g., of a and e, respectively, using c as the reference group), whereas the interaction term between infector and infectee infector : infectee introduces four interaction terms (e.g., of Aa, Ae, Ea, and Ee, respectively, since C and c are the reference groups in the main effects). Including the intercept, there are 1 + 2 + 2 + 4 = 9 parameters to estimate, corresponding to the odds or probability among the nine infector-infectee groups. The model formula in R is
glm(cbind(infected, exposed) ~ 1 + infector + infectee + infector : infectee, family = binomial(link = "logit"), data = ...)

The required data structure is a frequency table



infected
exposed
infector
infectee




$n_\text{Cc}$
$N_\text{Cc}$
C
c


$n_\text{Ca}$
$N_\text{Ca}$
C
a


$n_\text{Ce}$
$N_\text{Ce}$
C
e


$n_\text{Ac}$
$N_\text{Ac}$
A
c


$n_\text{Aa}$
$N_\text{Aa}$
A
a


$n_\text{Ae}$
$N_\text{Ae}$
A
e


$n_\text{Ec}$
$N_\text{Ec}$
E
c


$n_\text{Ea}$
$N_\text{Ea}$
E
a


$n_\text{Ec}$
$N_\text{Ee}$
E
e



I believe that you can model the same data by a loglinear regression. Because the response variable is case count out of group size, which follows a binomial process instead of binary responses among individual patients, you need to examine the overdispersion issue.

From the perspective child-to-x, for example, say there were 2000 child-to-child infections, 4000 child-to-adult and 2000 child-to-older. Can I say, the risks of child to child infection was 10%; child to adults was 20%; and child to elderly people was 10%.

No, this interpretation is incorrect. The absolute size of each exposed group does not affect the expected risk or infection probability if sampling within each group was random and representative. The group size only matters in translating the risk (infection probability) into the total expected count of infected people and its proportion among the none groups. These two parts (i.e., expected risk vs. expected count) are separate research questions and should be studied with different data sources. Most epidemiological survey attack the first problem from some samples possibly with stratification where certain populations (e.g., with few infected cases or complex mechanism) are oversampled. For example, we may consider that the adult group here is oversampled. The child-adult ratio might be much higher than 1 : 3 in the population. However, this does not matter in calculating odds ratios between groups, even if the infected are oversampled for rare diseases, which is the beauty of logit models. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_regression#Case-control_sampling. To address the second question, we will apply this fitted model of expected risks onto a different data source, which usually comes from census, that describes the actual demographic split among all residents. If case-control sampling is used (recruiting was done based on the outcome instead of predictors), the intercept value need to be reestimated.

For the exposed value in the frequency table, assuming all people in the population are equally exposed, do I sum both age-group populations (infector and infectee)? In which case, for C, c, it would be 2x the child population (in example 2x 20,000)? First row according to example, would be 2000, 40,000, C, c  - correct?

No, do not double count. The exposed count should be recorded before infections take place. It needs to be the "potential market size" before "market entry." So for the first row, $N_\text{Cc}$ needs to be the count of children who have access to children infectors but are all healthy at the study beginning time. The number of initial children infectors should not be included in $N_\text{Cc}$ but can be used as another predictor (add a 5th column in the frequency table).
